# alert() not showing on iPhone in webview

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I just noticed that `alert()` doesn't work in my iPhone webview app. I don't understand at all what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code where i display webview -

```
WebView(
                  key: _key,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  initialUrl: url,
                  gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                    setState(() {
                      webViewController = controller;
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

And here is the package version I am using - `webview_flutter: ^3.0.4`

Tell me, what do I need to do so that the `alert ()` is displayed correctly in my application?

Alert() is called on an event inside the site. Accordingly, I do not call it. On Android it shows up, but on iPhone nothing happens. I have spent many hours looking for a solution, but have never been able to find a solution. I would be grateful for any help or idea

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @SyedRehan No, unfortunately it has not been resolved. Maybe you have solutions?